# C Queue, Duplicating elements in sorted order

Tags: c, queue

So

if I have a queue

```
a --> b --> NULL;
```

and when I use a function

```
void duplicate(QueueNodePtr pHead, QueueNodePtr *pTail)
```

it will give

```
a --> a --> b --> b --> NULL
```

I can't get around my head with sorting with just reference of tail.

all I could do is

```
a --> b --> a --> b --> NULL
```

how would you approach this?

basic code is fine but what I need is hint,

Thanks!

Comment: Queues are all about insertion order, so you should not be able to tamper with that. Besides, please change your tagging to c++ instead of c

Comment: In your question, `**a --> a --> b --> b --> NULL**` what do the double asteriks signify?

Comment: why c++? Im working in c

Comment: sorry about c and c++, you're right. The other I keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out the number of elements in the queue (N), then you can simply do the following:

```
for i = 1 to N
  e = remove(queue)
  insert(queue, e)
  insert(queue, e)
```

You will get each element duplicated using queue operations.

If you want to manipulate the data directly, then it's no longer a queue - it's a (linked) list.

Comment: I thought of deleting it and putting it back, I guess that's the only way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pop items from the queue and push them, twice, into a new queue?

edit: If you need the original queue to store the results, what's stopping you from popping those items from the temporary queue and pushing back into the original queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a brief pseudo-code below which tries to achieve your objective

```
void duplicateQueue(QueueNode *head, QueueNode *tail)
{
    QueueNode *curr;
    QueueNode *node;

    //Initialize curr to head
    curr = head
    do
    {
        // Create a new node
        node = (QueueNode *) malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));

        // Initilaize the node
        node->data = curr->data;

        // Create link from node to curr->next
        node->next = curr->next;

        //Create a link from current to new node
        curr->next = node;

        // move current to next original element
        curr = node->next;

    }while(curr != NULL);
```

}

Comment: Thanks but head must be passed by value!

Comment: @user1420929 Sorry, I didn't get your comment. A reference to head value would have to be passed. Or did you mean that you would like to duplicate from some middle point in the entire collection?